# Getting Mongo database values in forEach loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, foreach

I have two schemas Teacher and Student

```
StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email:{type:String, index: {unique:true}}
name:{type:String},
marks:[{
subject:{type:String,
marks:{type:Number}
}]
})


TeacherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email:{type:String, index: {unique:true}}
name:{type:String},
students:[{
email:{type:String},
registerationDate:{type:Date}
}]
})
```

I have an API where I get teacher's email id and have to respond with marks and name of the students registered to that particular teacher.

For this, I'm using this code

```
var teacher = await Teacher.findOne({"email":req.body.email})

teacher.students.forEach(function(students){
let student = Student.findOne({"email":students.email})
console.log(student)   // to watch the result
})
```

I want to get the complete Student schema in my student variable so that I can use the data of the students.

But I'm not getting the desired output because I can't user await along with Student.findOne.

Like this

```
let student = await Student.findOne({"email":students.email})
```

I'm getting a Query object as a result.

Can anyone suggest any way to use await in the loop or any other way to get my desired output?

Node crashes if I use await anywhere inside my loop, so solutions answered elsewhere to use async/await in loop is not solving my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: @DragonBorn I have tried solutions answered by the people in that post but node crashes if i use await anywhere inside my loop, so it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: And what error did you get when it crashed and did you use `for of` instead of `forEach` ?

Comment: @DragonBorn I got this error :TypeError: this.$__path is not a function

Comment: Can you include the code that you tried from the other post which gave this error. Please include the whole function starting from your `async`.

Comment: @DragonBorn Whenever I use await inside for loop or forEach loop I get this error.

Comment: You cannot use `await` inside `forEach` or `for` loop, you have to use `for of` loop like this `for (let student of teacher.students) { //code here }`

Comment: @DragonBorn Yeah, it worked thanks a lot buddy. But I didn't see this on that other question.

Comment: I have added that as an answer. You can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use await inside a `forEach` loop. You have to use a `for .. of` loop instead.

A `forEach` loop fires of multiple asynchronous requests but the function immediately returns after that. It does not wait for your promise to resolve while a `for .. of` loop does.

Change your code to:

```
for (let students of teacher.students) {
  let student = Student.findOne({"email":students.email})
  console.log(student)   // to watch the result
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** There is no native synchronous API for Mongoose queries but you can chain the queries.

Try this one;

```
Teacher.findOne({"email":req.body.email}, (err, teacher)=>{
    if( !err ) {
      let studentEmailIds = [];
      teacher.students.forEach( (students) => {
          studentEmailIds.push(students.email);
      });
      Student.find({'email': {"$in": studentEmailIds } }, (err, students)=>{     
         if(err){
          //error handle
         }else{
          console.log(students)
          //res.json(students);
         }
      });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forEach you can use find function of mongoose like below:

```
teacher.find({}, function (err, teachers) {
  // now you can use teachers.forEach here for getting students
  console.log(teachers.students)
});
```

I suppose you are trying to get all Teachers with their students.

Comment: Students should be in teachers, Can you put debug on the commented line and send me what is inside in teachers.

Comment: I don't get it which one are you asking, the one inside my question or the one in your answer?

Comment: I mean try my answer and watch teachers. teacher.find({}, function (err, teachers) {
  // now you can use teachers.forEach here for getting students 
console.log(teachers.students)
});

Comment: Node crashed without any error message [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question, this should help

```
Teacher.find({}, (error, allTeachers) => {
  if (error) {
    // Handle Error
  } else {
    allTeachers.forEach(teacher=> {
      let student = Student.findOne({"email":teacher.email})
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: My Node keeps on crashing using your code without displaying the error message inside the if condition.

Comment: I made a syntax error, it's fixed now, you could try it

Comment: It still crashes the same.

Comment: I think it's cos i used teacher.findOne instead of Teacher.findOne. Try changing that.
Also, what error do you get when it crashes?

Comment: It doesn't show any error it straight away crashes.

Comment: I have console.log inside the if

Comment: And are you getting the log??